# what is the code mean? self.plusOne(digits[:-1]) digits.extend([0])

Tags: python

```
digits = self.plusOne(digits[:-1])
digits.extend([0])
```

The full code:

```
def plusOne(self, digits):
    """
    :type digits: List[int]
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    if len(digits) == 0:
        digits = [1]
    elif digits[-1] == 9:
        digits = self.plusOne(digits[:-1])
        digits.extend([0])
    else:
        digits[-1] += 1
    return digits
```

Answer (score 2):

```
elif digits[-1] == 9:
    digits = self.plusOne(digits[:-1])
    digits.extend([0])
```

> else if the last value in the list digits is a 9:
>   set digits = self.plusOne(all numbers in digits except the last)
>   add the number 0
>   to the list digits

For example:

```
digits = [9, 0, 9]
# digits = [9, 0, 9]
digits = self.plusOne([9, 0]) # this returns [9, 1]
# digits = [9, 1]
digits.extend([0])
# digits = [9, 1, 0]
```